# How include node_modules in output directory with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

I want to know if it possible copy node_modules folder into output directory after run tsc command.

My situation it that I have a project with TypeScript and use some npm packages. And i need that my output directory has all npm dependencies, because i need to compress it and send by http (to AWS Lambda).

My project structure is like this:

```
|-.vscode --> visual studio code
|-lib --> output dir
|-node_modules --> npm dependencies
|-src --> .ts files
|-jsconfig.json
|-tsconfig.json
```

How can achieve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to just `cp` the directory over. If you want to automate it you can wrap your `tsc` and `cp` calls up in npm scripts in your package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc <your command line options>",
        "postbuild": "cp -R node_modules lib/node_modules"
    }
}
```

Then when you use `npm run build` your `cp` command should automatically run as well.

Comment: But what if you only want `dependencies` not `devDependencies`?

Comment: @CoreyCole i've answered it in my answer

Answer (score 69):

I like [Peopleware's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42162316/6598814) solution a lot more than the accepted solution, but you don't even need gulp for that. You can simply do this in your package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc <your command line options>",
    "postbuild": "cp package.json dist/package.json && cd dist && npm install --only=production"
  }
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you're not copying the entirety of your `node_modules` folder, because it might have a ton of dependencies only used during development.

You can do the same with static assets such as images or what not with:

```
"copy-statics": "cp -r static dist/static"
```

**Update:** instead of using `npm install --only-production` it is safer to copy both `package.json` *and* `package-lock.json` and then run `npm ci --production`. This ensures that you only install the dependency snapshot that you have in your `package-lock.json`. So the command would look like this:

```
"postbuild": "cp package*.json dist && cd dist && npm ci --production"
```

Comment: Don't forget the lock file!

Comment: @RichardTuin Good point but with `npm install` the lock file might get modified anyway. So perhaps the better solution would be to copy the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and then instead of `npm install` run `npm ci`.

Comment: `tsc` can copy the package.json and lock file on compilation if `resolveJsonModule` is enabled and the package files included in build. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836908/how-to-copy-package-json-in-dist-or-build-folder-when-running-tsc-typescript-co

Comment: 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Excelent aproach, thanks. Just one thing to add. You can run the install command in a sub-shell (wrapping the command in parentheses) to avoid that cd command change your directory. `"postbuild": "cp package*.json dist && (cd dist && npm ci --omit=dev --ignore-scripts)"`

Answer (score 8):

For this purpose I created a simple [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) task.

*gulpfile.js:*

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var install = require('gulp-install');

const PROD_DEST = '../dist';

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./package.json'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PROD_DEST))
        .pipe(install({
            args: ['only=production']
        }));
});
```

---

`package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build:prod": "tsc && gulp"
}
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
},
...
```

This way I can run `npm run build:prod` to transpile the TypeScript sources into `PROD_DEST`.
`gulp` copies the `package.json` into that folder and runs `npm install --only=production` in it which installs **only the runtime dependencies**.
This approach is **cleaner** if you have a lot of devDependencies and **platform independent**.

Answer (score 8):

This solution is an improvement of the naive "copy the whole folder" solution. **It copy-paste only needed dependencies and/or devDependencies from the source node_modules to the target folder**. Only works on POSIX environments. If cross-platform is mandatory then I advice you to stick to the `cp` strategy or a node-js script.

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc <your command line options>",
        "postbuild": "out='lib/node_modules' && root=$(npm root) && mkdir -p $out && npm ls --production --parseable | tail --lines=+2 | sed \"s%$root%%\" | cut --delimiter='/' --fields=2 | sort | uniq | xargs -I % cp -r \"$root/%\" $out"
    }
}
```

**You can list only dependencies or devDependencies respectively with `--production` and `--development` flags of the [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ls) command**

### How it works

```sh
out='lib/node_modules' \               # output dir relative to package.json
&& root=$(npm root) \                  # get path to node_modules dir
&& mkdir -p $out \
&& npm ls --production --parseable \   # (1)
| tail --lines=+2 \                    # (2)
| sed "s%$root%%" \                    # (3)
| cut --delimiter='/' --fields=2 \     # (4)
| sort | uniq \                        # (5) optional
| xargs -I % cp -r "$root/%" $out      # (6)
```

*(1)* List packages. We use [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ls) which lists installed packages in tree form. Note that the default format output contains superfluous information and packages can be listed multiple times. Thus we use the `--parseable` flag.

```
$ npm ls --parseable                                           
/home/code
/home/code/node_modules/mongoose
/home/code/node_modules/is-typed-array
/home/code/node_modules/is-typed-array/node_modules/es-abstract
...
```

*(2)* remove the first output line because we won't use it. Here package *is-typed-array* has its own copy of package *es-abstract*.

```
/home/code/node_modules/mongoose
/home/code/node_modules/is-typed-array
/home/code/node_modules/is-typed-array/node_modules/es-abstract
...
```

*(3)* remove node_modules path from each package path.

```
/mongoose
/is-typed-array
/is-typed-array/node_modules/es-abstract
...
```

*(4)* keep the first path member

```
/mongoose
/is-typed-array
/is-typed-array
...
```

*(5)* remove the duplicate lines. This step is optional but recommended as we won't copy the same package multiple times. However it can slow down the whole process.

```
mongoose
is-typed-array
...
```

*(6)* final step: copy. You can log the executed actions with `xargs -t`

```
cp -r /home/code/node_modules/is-typed-array lib/node_modules
cp -r /home/code/node_modules/mongoosee lib/node_modules
...
```

Comment: This is bar for the cleanest way to do it and it works flawlessly—how is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: I really like this answer, however I've noticed that dependencies having the scoped packages `@somescope/somepackagename` don't get copied.  Maybe there is some bash wizardry that could pull those in too.

Comment: FWIW here is what I ended up doing to include the scoped packages. `"postbuild": "rm -rf dist/node_modules && npm ls --only prod --parseable | tail -n +2 | xargs -n1 sh -c 'for arg do echo \"$arg\"; XDIR=$(echo \"$arg\" | xargs dirname | sed -E \"s/(.+node_modules)+(\\/@.+)?/dist\\/node_modules\\2/g\"); mkdir -p $XDIR; echo $XDIR; done' _ | xargs -n2 cp -r"`

Comment: @SteffenT while this is better than the accepted answer, it's not a particularly good answer because it wouldn't work on Windows unless one has compliant versions of tail, uniq, xargs, etc. meanwhile the highest upvoted answer only relies on cp, which works in PowerShell (default shell in VS Code on Windows).

Many of the things done here are already covered by `npm install --only=production` anyway.

Comment: @KerimGüney Thanks for the reminder, I've added a warning about crossplatform support. I like the copy package.json + install strategy because it can leverage the npm cache and even work offline if cache is up to date. However npm will always output in folder named `node_modules` which can be a burden for some usage.

Comment: @serrulien You're right, I didn't think of that. Upvoted <3

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but I was able to do this by running copying `package.json` into the `/dist` folder and running `yarn install`. Build script goes something like this:

1. `tsc` -> ts files into `/dist`
2. Copy `package.json` (using ts-node) into `/dist`
3. Copy `./src/views` into `/dist/views` (for Express)
4. `cd ./dist` then `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply use jenkins post build action and define as below

```
cp -R target/classes/static ../../../uistatic/dev
```

You can choose a path of your choice.