# How to copy package.json in dist or build folder when running tsc (TypeScript compiler)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, package.json, tsc

I have a TypeScript React component that uses a `package.json` file (see screenshot) and I run `tsc` in order to transpile it to es5 in my `dist` folder but the `package.json` file doesn't get copied. Please note that in the screenshot I manually copied it in the `dist` folder.

[image: component screenshot]

So my question: Is there a way to do this via `tsc/tsconfig` ... without having to add a copy script (ran via `yarn build`). Because I would like this to be updated also when running `tsc --watch`

Also I do NOT wish to rename my Component.tsx to index.tsx in the component folders. I don't want to have 200 index.tsx files in my project and using the `package.json`'s `main` allow me to have `import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent'` instead of doing `import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent/SomeComponent'` so it's great.

Here is my `tsconfig` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Many thanks for your time and your help or suggestions.

Comment: It would seem like an unusual way to utilize `package.json`. If your intention was to create a _monorepo_, perhaps it's a better idea to use a tool like Lerna to publish your micro components? TypeScript compiler will only convert `.ts` files into `.js` ones (and create corresponding `.d.ts` declarations). It cannot be used to manipulate anything else.

Comment: @KarolMajewski I will look into lerna. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471152/tell-typescript-to-compile-json-files. I had a similar issue with a nodejs project, which was fixed by changing my `require` to be an `import` while using the "resolveJsonModule" flag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just include it in your `tsconfig.json` file and enable the `resolveJsonModule` compiler option. You can do this by merging the following config into your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["./package.json"]
}
```

Comment: That's messing with the resulting folder structure of my build. :( I guess I'll just copy it manually.

Comment: @cbdeveloper do this "include": ["./package.json", "./*"]

Comment: Also remember to remove private from package.json