# Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: nestjs

Couple of weeks ago I installed NestJS globally on my computer.
Now I'm coming back to that, to start learning.

So I created new project with comand:

```
nest new ./
```

It generated all the files, but when I try to run this application with command:

```
nest start
```

I expected this template project to start but there are errors with importing paths?
Is this due to version of my installed Nest or something?

Errors on the screen:
[image]

Version of my Nest:
`7.5.6`

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.13",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.13",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.13",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.6",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.2.7",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.2",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  },
```

Comment: `nest new` should install dependencies for you. But just in case, can you run your package manager of choice's install command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same issue. The following two commands fixed it:

```
npm install @nestjs/common
npm install @nestjs/core
```

These commands make sure you are using the lastest versions of those packages.

Sometimes you may also get error: `Cannot find module '@nestjs/mapped-types' or its corresponding type declarations.`

In that case, do:

```
npm install @nestjs/mapped-types
```

Comment: same issue but i'm using yarn 3x and want to use Plug 'N play but somehow it still requires me to do this and get the node_module directory before it works :(

Comment: I installed these packages, but I encountered a problem after installing them. When I cut whole the import line and paste it again from scratch, it worked for me. :D

Comment: The comment by Mohammad Bactually worked for me. IDK why tho ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
npm i --save @nestjs/config
```

Reference: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Answer (score 3):

I've stuck with this problem when I built a nodejs application (like, express, nestjs, etc.)

So when you build a nodejs app, **the build(dist) folder just contains your code, not node_modules**.

You can copy node modules to a build folder, like:

```
cp package.json build/package.json && cd build && npm install --only=production
```

Or try [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109461/how-include-node-modules-in-output-directory-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

After running npm install, restarting Visual studio code did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions above helped me.

**My solution:**

1. Open "**package.json**" and find "**@nestjs/core**": "X.X.X",
2. Uninstall all packages whose name starts with "@nestjs/..."

### *(Uninstall only those that have the same version as "@nestjs/core": **9.1.1**)*

```
npm uninstall @nestjs/core @nestjs/common @nestjs/microservices @nestjs/platform-express
```

3. Install packages again

### *(Include version after @)*

```
npm i @nestjs/core@9.1.1 @nestjs/common@9.1.1 @nestjs/microservices@9.1.1 @nestjs/platform-express@9.1.1*
```

Comment: This was the only suggestion that really worked, with just some small adjustment to the version, thanks!

What worked for me:

pnpm i @nestjs/axios@3.0.1 @nestjs/config@3.1.1 @nestjs/swagger@7.1.14 @nestjs/core@9.1.1 @nestjs/common@9.1.1 @nestjs/microservices@9.1.1 @nestjs/platform-express@9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal "npm install --save @nestjs/config"

Answer (score 0):

Use npm or Yarn version 1.Yarn version 3 was the problem for me. It by default does not create node_modules folder. It uses different approach. Which causes the problem.

Comment: You're right. And how do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue today.
The reason were changes recently made to yarn.lock, which led to some module resolution issues for nestjs (other apps were just fine).
Rebuilding yarn.lock did not help, neither did ensuring consistent versions between `@nestjs/*` packages or running reinstalls.

I had to restore `yarn.lock` to the last working version and run `yarn install` to bring it to the up-to-date state. Then it all worked.

*We have a big monorepo (yarn-3 workspaces, pnp) with a load of apps and shared packages.

**I am still wandering what is the reason behind it. Looks like some initial setup (happening when adding nestjs app to monorepo) set up something extra, something which yarn-3.6.0 with pnp workspaces monorepo does not handle...

Answer (score 0):

Русский:
После того как был создан проект с помощью "@nest/cli" необходима инициализация "npm" и делается она таким способом:
`npm i`.
либо
`npm --install`
English:
After the project was created using "@nest/cli", initialization of "npm" is necessary and it is done in this way:`npm i`. or `npm --install`

Рад был помочь.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?