# Can Electron JS execute a child process with a different node_modules context?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I'm using Electron JS to package a node application, but now I need to create a server application which is headless, which will run in parallel to the Electron JS application.

I'd like Electron to start a node child process.

The problem is that this server application should have its own node_modules folder.

Is there a way to use Electron JS to execute a node aplication as a child process (taking advantage of the fact that the user will have already a Node environment, e.g. Electron JS) but in a different context? E.g. with it's own node_modules. Basically it should be a child process without relation to the parent (the only relation would be that it's also a node process).

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You should be able to do it if you provide another entry point for the `electron.exe` or however you named it for packaging.

For example, before packaging you could add a code in the main js file that you are using for electron, that dynamically requires modules based on receiving different process arguments.

Comment: I didn't think about having different arguments in the same executable. That could work. The only problem is that my Electron setup uses webpack to bundle all the Javascript files, but some things don't work well with webpack (e.g. socket.io server version). I should include somehow the node_modules for the child process in the executable, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: You could exclude some of the modules from being bundled by webpack and you could supply them in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a child_process can use it's own node_modules due to [how node resolves require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305668/4418836) describes how to install node_modules for your headless server at build time by running `cp package.json headless-server/package.json && cp package-lock.json headless-server/package-lock.json && cd headless-server/ && npm install --only production`

Then make sure you ship your electron app with the `headless-server` folder and in your electron app execute the following:

```js
const localServerChildProcess = child_process.fork(
    path.join(__dirname, 'headless-server/ENTRYPOINT.js'),
    [],
    { silent: false }
);
localServerChildProcess.on('message', (d) => console.log('message', d));
localServerChildProcess.on('error', (e) => console.error('child process error', e));
```

Side note: `{ silent: false }` allows the child_process's logs to print to the same place as the electron app logs.